# Using the specific timezone instead of the server timezone

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

[GridView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/miG7s.png)

```
  DateTimeOffset serverTime = DateTimeOffset.Now;
         
            DateTimeOffset localTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(serverTime, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Singapore Standard Time"));


     if (localTime.Date >= eddate.Date && localTime.Date <= stdate.Date)
            {
                if (localTime >= sttime && localTime <= edtime)
                {

                    MySqlConnection MyConn2 = new MySqlConnection(MyConnection2);
                    MySqlCommand MyCommand2 = new MySqlCommand(query, MyConn2);
                    MySqlDataReader MyReader2;
                    MyConn2.Open();
                    MyReader2 = MyCommand2.ExecuteReader();
                    Label2.Text = "Thank you for You Vote";
                    //  System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine();

                }
                else
                {
                    Label2.Text = "Please check the eletion time!";
                    Label2.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Label2.Text = "Please check the eletion date !";
                Label2.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Purple;
            }
```

I'm trying to get the date in the timezone that I specified(Singapore Standard Time) and compare it with the date I displayed in gridview. I'm able to use the Singapore Standard Time when validating the time. However, for the date, It still not able to get the date in Singapore Standard Time.

Comment: `DateTime` knows nothing about timezones. It's only a date+time value without offset.  If you care about timezones use `DateTimeOffset`. A `DateTime` can be `UTC`, `Local` or `Unknown`, with any values coming from external systems like the database treated as `Unknown`

Comment: I can use the 'DateTimeOffset' to get the date in the timezone that I specified(China Standard Time)? Because my local time is the same as the China Standard Time, therefore I would like to use the China Standard Time instead of the hosting server time

Comment: Hi, I'm using the DateTimeOffSet now. I'm still not able to get the correct date in the specific timezone

Comment: There is no reason to have a separate variable for Date and DateTime.  You can get Date from DateTime

Comment: Show the code again, using `DateTimeOffset` *only*.  Do not use `DateTime` anywhere.

Comment: Hi, I had updated to code. I can use the LocalTime.Date to get the date in the specific timezone? The reason I separate the time and time is that I store the date and time as shown in the picture and I want to validate the correct date and time with the one display in the gridview

Comment: I'm using the localTime.Date, but I still not able to get the correct date

Comment: Add `Console.WriteLine($"serverTime: {serverTime}; localTime: {localTime}");` and post what it says.

Answer (score 0):

This code converts the server time to Singapore time.

```
DateTimeOffset serverTime = DateTimeOffset.Now;
DateTimeOffset singaporeTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(serverTime,
  TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Singapore Standard Time"));
```

Do not use `DateTime` **anywhere** in your code, only use `DateTimeOffset`.

Also there is no reason to have separate variables for date and time.  `DateTimeOffset` is all you need.  (Use the `.Date` property to get the date from a `DateTimeOffset`)